# how to get value of input tag in array with same attribute name in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i want to get value of first input tag in eduction [0] and value of second input tag in education[1]
education is array.

```
<input  type="text" name="education" value={this.state.education[0]} onChange={this.handleChange}  
class="form-control"  />
<input type="text"  name="education" value={this.state.education[1]} onChange={ 
this.handleChange()} class="form-control"/>
```

Comment: Your second input should be onChange={this.handleChange}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to do it as follow (It allow you to dynamically create your inputs and also if you don't want dynamic input you can use the same technique as well)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      education: ["", ""] // I've added 2 items to create 2 inputs
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

handleChange(e) {
    const education = [...this.state.education];
    education[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      education: education
    });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.education.map((item, index) => (
          <input
            id={index}
            type="text"
            name="education"
            value={this.state.education[index]}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            class="form-control"
          />
        ))
        }
      </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second input you (by mistake i think) added `()` after your `this.handleChange` function. This means this function will be called immediately and won't be called onChange.